# Using an array to point to an object and printing to the screen?

Tags: c#, arrays, object, pointers

I'm having problems with using an array to point to an object then printing the content of that object to the screen.

So far my code is:

```
 //Card
        Card cardPack = new Card();
        string[] myCard = new string[10];

        //card objects
        Card cardOne = new Card();
        {
            cardPack.name = "Vodka";
            cardPack.percentage = '5';
            cardPack.quality = '6';
            cardPack.quantity = '4';
            cardPack.taste = '3';
        }
```

As far as I know this code works because I don't have any type of error.

```
        //Card Array
        myCard[0] = Convert.ToString(cardOne);
```

I am then using this to point to the actual object, again this doesn't error so I assume it is working correctly.

```
            Console.WriteLine(myCard[0]);
```

This also doesn't error but when I try and run the program the only output I get is

```
   "Card"
```

I'm very confused! 
Can you please help me? Thank you!

Comment: Convert.ToString() simply gets the objects type name. If you want to get more than just the type name you need to override ToString on the Card class - all types in the .NET framework subclass object and object contains a ToString() virtual method

Comment: How would I do that? Sorry I haven't been doing this for very long?

Comment: What do you want to do? Just get the name of a card, or call a method that returns a description of the whole card? (That would be an overridden `ToString()` in Card)

Comment: @Kjartan I would like to output everything that is present inside the cardOne object, so I would like the output to be:
Vodka
5
6
4
3

Comment: Then my guess was correct :) - just store the whole object in the array (of type `Card`), and call an overridden `ToString()` in that class.

Comment: Both overriding the method and the other way of storing items in arrays should be considered by OP, since both aspects of solving such things occur a lot. I'm just putting this note here since I'm unsure about the OP's experience...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an object and converting it to a String instead of taking the name. That results in outputting the name of the object type, namely 'Card'.

Try this:

```
//Card Array
myCard[0] = cardOne.name;
```

Even better would be to change your array:

```
//string[] myCard = new string[10];
Card[] myCard = new Card[10];
myCard[0] = cardOne;
Console.WriteLine(myCard[0].name);
```

Ofcourse you can override the `ToString()` method but I'm guessing this isn't what you want.

EDIT: After reading your comment about your preferred output, this code might do as you want:

```
Console.WriteLine("Name: " + myCard[0].name);
Console.WriteLine("Percentage: " + myCard[0].percentage);
Console.WriteLine("Quality: " + myCard[0].quality);
Console.WriteLine("Quantity: " + myCard[0].quantity);
Console.WriteLine("Taste: " + myCard[0].taste);
Console.WriteLine("");
```

or as you said:

```
Console.Write("myCard[0].name);
Console.Write(" " + myCard[0].percentage);
Console.Write(" " + myCard[0].quality);
Console.Write(" " + myCard[0].quantity);
Console.Write(" " + myCard[0].taste);
Console.WriteLine("");
```

Please note this only works when you have  your array converted to an array of Card's, by using `Card[] myCard = new Card[10];`(consider changing the name from 'myCard' to 'allCards' or something like that.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Sorry I didn't explain myself very well, the only problem with this is instead of outputting vodka, 5.. etc it outputs *space* 0, 0, 0, 0?

Comment: You can also try `Console.Write(..)` instead of `WriteLine`. Using WriteLine, it'll automatically go to the next line. Let me edit to clarify.

Comment: @ValerieBeighton I've edited my answer, try and see if that fits your needs.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you very much! This has been driving me crazy for hours!! Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: @ValerieBeighton consider accepting the answer if you thought it was usefull.

Answer (score 3):

You need to override `ToString()` method to be able to do this.

See the below code as a sample:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    string stringForm = string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}", name,percentage, quality, quantity, taste);
    return stringForm;
}
```

Comment: This to me sounds more like what the OP wants, I get a PHP vibe from the question (like array_print in PHP maybe?). Though to correct this post, an object can be converted to a string - the CLR just calls ToString() on the object in question

Answer (score 1):

Override the ToString method of the Card class.

```
 public class Card
 {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
         return string.Format("CardName: {0}", Name);
    }
 }
```

After that, you can store the Card objects in a Card array, and the WriteLine will show the proper value(set in the ToString()) on the console.

```
Card[] myCard = new Card[10];

Card cardOne = new Card();
cardOne.name = ...

 myCard[0] = cardOne;
 Console.WriteLine(myCard[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Covert.ToString converts the CardOne object to a string. This means that is converts the class name. You should convert a explicit object in your class.

- edit
  Joetjah just showed you what i meant.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot print an object as it is.

`Console.WriteLine(myCard[0]);` prints the type of the object and thats why it returns `"Card"`.

So you will have to access each member of the object and then print it.

So to get the member you have to use `mycard[index].<member name>`
eg: `mycard[0].name`

I hope this helped you, else please let me know.

Comment: `myCard` is an array of strings so that's should be ok

Comment: @David S:still if u print an object it returns the type

Comment: Yes, but I'm just saying that `myCard` doesn't contain `Card` objects. (maybe it should, but that's another thing)

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is:

```
Card[] myCard = new Card[10];

(...)

myCard[0] = cardOne;
```

Then this:

```
Console.WriteLine(myCard[0].ToString());
```

...will output the result of calling the `ToString()`-method of the type/class `Card`.

I'm assuming that's what you wanted?

**Update**; Add something like this to your `Card` class

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return name + " " 
               + percentage + " "  
               + quality + " "  
               + quantity + " "  
               + taste + " " );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you get as output is the name of the Object that you store in cardOne, that is, a "Card" object.

If what you want is "Vodka", your code  should  be something similar to:

```
//Card Array
myCard[0] = Convert.ToString(cardOne.name);
```

And since name is already an string, you could simplify it to:

```
//Card Array
myCard[0] = cardOne.name;
```